# iPhone/Obj C: Why does convert float to int: (int) float * 100 does not work?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, floating-point, int

In my code, I am using float to do currency calculation but the rounding has yielded undesired results so I am trying to convert it all to int. With as little change to the infrastructure as possible, in my init functions, I did this:

```
-(id)initWithPrice:(float)p;
{
[self setPrice:(int)(p*100)];
}
```

I multiply by 100 b/c in the main section, the values are given as .xx to 2 decimals. I abnormally I notice is that for float 1.18, the int rounds it to 117. Does anyone know it does that? The float leaves it as 1.18. I expect it to be 118 for the int equiv in cents.

Thanks.

Comment: If at all possible, I would try to use NSDecimalNumber instead of floats to store currency values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Floating point is always a little imprecise.   With IEEE floating point encoding, powers of two can be represented exactly (like 4,2,1,0.5,0.25,0.125,0.0625,...) , but numbers like 0.1 are always an approximation (just try representing it as a sum of powers of 2).

Your (int) cast will truncate whatever comes in, so if p*100 is resolving to 117.9999995 due to this imprecision , that will become 1.17 instead of 1.18.

Better solution is to use something like roundf on p*100.    Even better would be if you can go upstream and fully convert to fixed-point math using integers in the entire program.

Comment: Or for short: never ever use `float`, `double`, or `long double` when dealing with money. Ever.

Comment: Amen to that!  Unless you're intentionally biasing the rounding to put the delta into your own bank account.

Comment: OK. Thanks. It is not 117.99999999995 because in my code, the init is something like this: Item *item = [[Item alloc] initWithPrice:1.18] and when I do NSLog(%f, %i) for the float version and the int version, I get 1.18 for float and 117 for int. I upvoted the comments here but it is technically not an answer. If someone has an answer, I will mark it as such.

Comment: @Yko: You haven't actually established that "it is not 117.99999999995." The fact that you wrote "1.18" doesn't matter if the datatype can't represent that number, and doing `NSLog(@"%f", 1.18)` will not tell you anything useful, because it rounds. Do `NSLog(@"%1.20f", 1.18)` instead and it will show you the true number.

Comment: @Yko: Chuck is right.  Try this:  plug 1.18 into digitconvert.com to see it in binary and hex.   Now copy the hex value, re-open digitconvert.com, and paste the hex value into the hex bucket.  The decimal number comes out to 1.17999999...   So the hex and binary value isn't an exact representation,  at least with 56 bits of mantissa. That's likely true regardless how many bits you add.  It's the same as trying to represent 1/3 as 0.33333...you never quite get there no matter how many bits you add. That's what's happening in your program.

Comment: The inexact representation is the issue, but there's an easy solution -- just do (int)(100 * p + .5); if you assume that your numbers are the closest machine representable version of a number with two decimal places, then this will always work.